# prevent controls from disappearing in Azure Media Player

Tags: azure-media-services

In Azure Media Player, by default the control bar (i.e. where the timeline and play controls appear) starts as visible. But if you don't move your mouse then it disappears after 5 seconds.  Is there a way to suppress the disappearance, so that the control bar is always visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, I checked [Azure Media Player](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html), but did not find any options to always show the controls.

Per my test, you could use `setInterval()` method to call a function to explicitly set class `vjs-user-active` on your `video` element for the workaround as follows:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.1.5/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.1.5/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
   <video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" tabindex="0"></video>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){

   var myOptions = {
    "nativeControlsForTouch": true,
    controls: true,
    autoplay: true,
    width: "640",
    height: "400",
    }
    myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
    myPlayer.src([
      {"src":"https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/cf2b/d75f604a-e59f-46f2-81d3-4ec1473ecf2b/AzureFridayGetStartedWithAzureFor_mid.mp4"}
    ]);

    var myInterval=setInterval(function(){
      $("#azuremediaplayer").removeClass("vjs-user-inactive");
      $("#azuremediaplayer").addClass("vjs-user-active");
    },1000);
})();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer, and thank you for it, but it still leaves something to be desired.  Every so often, say every 25 seconds, the control bar still disappears momentarily for a fraction of a second.  If vjs-user-inactive was a CSS style, I think a better way would be to redefine it to be identical to vjs-user-active.  But, as far as I can tell, it doesn't seem to be a style.

Comment: Actually I am wrong - vjs-user-inactive is in fact a CSS style.  So, one could make a copy of the azuremediaplayer.min.css where it's defined, and tweak that.